# String Enumeration Class with restricted set of values and special characters

Tags: vb.net, class, attributes

Have a class with a string attribute (usign vs 2005 here)

```
Private _foo As String
Public Property Foo() As String
    Get
        Return _foo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        ??
    End Set
End Property
```

I want to restric the values of Foo into a set list of values.
Unfortunately those values include special characters:
"bar/bar", "smthing/smthing" etc..
so I dont think I can use a simple enumeration

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this help where it checks an `arraylist` for allowed values and returns an error if it doesnt. Obviously not a strict as an enum

```
Public Class footest

    Private _foo As String

    Private allowed_values As ArrayList

    Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)

        MyBase.New()
        allowed_values.Add("bar/bar")
        allowed_values.Add("smthing/smthing")

    End Sub

    Public Property Foo() As String
        Get
            Return _foo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If allowed_values.Contains(value) Then
                _foo = value
            Else
                _foo = "NA#"
            End If

        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Or you could create your enum without the special characters then look them up in a hashtable/sortedlist/dictionary that you create in the `New` sub

```
Private hashtable As Hashtable

Public Sub New(ByVal text As String)

    MyBase.New()
    hashtable.Add("barbar", "bar/bar")
    hashtable.Add("smthingsmthing", "smthing/smthing")


End Sub
```

Comment: this works but what if the instance of this class is created hundreds of thousands times? This would mean that for each instance of "footest" class, another arrayList is created.

Answer (score 0):

Found this at CodeProject and it allows me to return an enum with special characters to the console and will require you to create 3 classes. To avoid creating new `arraylists` etc. at every new `foo` you need to be a bit more elaborate

- [String Enumerations in VB.NET @ CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33455/String-Enumerations-in-VB-NET')

[image]

*Console*

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim x As New _foo
        x.Foo = FooString.barbar

        Console.WriteLine(x.Foo)
    End Sub

End Module
```

*The foo class*

```
Public Class _foo
    Private _foo As String

    Public Property Foo() As FooString
        Get
            Return _foo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As FooString)
            _foo = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

*A custom enumeration that outputs special characters*

```
Public NotInheritable Class FooString
    Inherits StringEnumeration(Of FooString)

    ''ADD YOUR ALLOWED VALUES HERE
    Public Shared ReadOnly barbar As New FooString("Bar/Bar")
    Public Shared ReadOnly smthingsmthing As New FooString("smthing/smthing")


    Private Sub New(ByVal StringConstant As String)
        MyBase.New(StringConstant)
    End Sub

End Class
```

*A String enumeration handling class*

```
Public MustInherit Class StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration _
       As StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration))
    Implements IStringEnumeration

    Private myString As String
    Sub New(ByVal StringConstant As String)
        myString = StringConstant
    End Sub

#Region "Properties"
    Public Class [Enum]
        Public Shared Function GetValues() As String()
            Dim myValues As New List(Of String)
            For Each myFieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo _
                                 In GetSharedFieldsInfo()
                Dim myValue As StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration) = _
                  CType(myFieldInfo.GetValue(Nothing),  _
                  StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration))
                'Shared Fields use a Null object
                myValues.Add(myValue)
            Next
            Return myValues.ToArray
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GetNames() As String()
        Dim myNames As New List(Of String)
        For Each myFieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo _
                     In GetSharedFieldsInfo()
                myNames.Add(myFieldInfo.Name)
            Next
            Return myNames.ToArray
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GetName(ByVal myName As  _
               StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration)) As String
            Return myName
        End Function

        Public Shared Function isDefined(ByVal myName As String) As Boolean
            If GetName(myName) Is Nothing Then Return False
            Return True
        End Function

        Public Shared Function GetUnderlyingType() As Type
            Return GetType(String)
        End Function

        Friend Shared Function GetSharedFieldsInfo() _
                      As System.Reflection.FieldInfo()
            Return GetType(TStringEnumeration).GetFields
        End Function

        Friend Shared Function GetSharedFields() As  _
                      StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration)()
            Dim myFields As New List(Of  _
                         StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration))
            For Each myFieldInfo As System.Reflection.FieldInfo _
                                 In GetSharedFieldsInfo()
                Dim myField As StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration) = _
                    CType(myFieldInfo.GetValue(Nothing),  _
                    StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration))
                'Shared Fields use a Null object
                myFields.Add(myField)
            Next
            Return myFields.ToArray
        End Function
    End Class
#End Region

#Region "Cast Operators"
    'Downcast to String
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal myStringEnumeration _
           As StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration)) As String
        If myStringEnumeration Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        Return myStringEnumeration.ToString
    End Operator

    'Upcast to StringEnumeration
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal myString As String) As  _
                           StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration)
        For Each myElement As StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration) In _
                 StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration).Enum.GetSharedFields
            'Found a Matching StringEnumeration - Return it
            If myElement.ToString = myString Then Return myElement
        Next
        'Did not find a Match - return NOTHING
        Return Nothing
    End Operator

    Overrides Function ToString() As String Implements IStringEnumeration.ToString
        Return myString
    End Function
#End Region

#Region "Concatenation Operators"
    Public Shared Operator &(ByVal left As StringEnumeration(Of  _
           TStringEnumeration), ByVal right As StringEnumeration(Of  _
           TStringEnumeration)) As String
        If left Is Nothing And right Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        If left Is Nothing Then Return right.ToString
        If right Is Nothing Then Return left.ToString
        Return left.ToString & right.ToString
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator &(ByVal left As StringEnumeration(Of  _
           TStringEnumeration), ByVal right As IStringEnumeration) As String
        If left Is Nothing And right Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
        If left Is Nothing Then Return right.ToString
        If right Is Nothing Then Return left.ToString
        Return left.ToString & right.ToString
    End Operator
#End Region

#Region "Operator Equals"

    Public Shared Operator =(ByVal left As StringEnumeration(Of  _
           TStringEnumeration), ByVal right As  _
           StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration)) As Boolean
        If left Is Nothing Or right Is Nothing Then Return False
        Return left.ToString.Equals(right.ToString)
    End Operator

    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        If TypeOf (obj) Is StringEnumeration(Of TStringEnumeration) Then
            Return CType(obj, StringEnumeration(Of  _
                   TStringEnumeration)).ToString = myString
        ElseIf TypeOf (obj) Is String Then
            Return CType(obj, String) = myString
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
#End Region

#Region "Operator Not Equals"
    Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal left As StringEnumeration(Of  _
           TStringEnumeration), ByVal right As StringEnumeration(Of  _
           TStringEnumeration)) As Boolean
        Return Not left = right
    End Operator

#End Region

End Class

'Base Interface without any Generics for StringEnumerations
Public Interface IStringEnumeration
    Function ToString() As String
End Interface
```

Comment: you can add the `FooString` class to the bottom of the `_foo` class if you wish you save space and reduce number of classes